# Stop htaccess redirecting add on domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain redirecting to a maintenance page while we do some work on it. However I cant prevent it from redirecting an add-on-domain to the maintenance page.

The rule I'm using is as follows.....

```
Redirect /index.html http://domain.com/maintenance
```

What rule do I add to exclude addondomain.org

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `mod_rewrite` rules for that requirement. Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !addondomain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://domain.com/maintenance [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: I removed the old rule and added yours from above with substituting the addondomain with my variable and domain.com with my root domain variable but nothing redirects for me. The site is a joomla site. Would this cause any problems?

Comment: Yes you have to make sure this is **very first rule** just below `RewriteEngine On` in root .htaccess

Comment: Yes I have it exactly as you have suggested but still no joy, no redirect. Those three lines are the only three I have in the root access....... [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/2dsr989.png[/IMG]

Comment: If it is Joomla site then you  might be having some Joomla rules also? Where is that .htaccess located? Also what URL are you using to test this?

Comment: It is located in the public_html folder for the URL

Comment: I asked 3 questions in my comment if you notice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58783/discussion-between-hotshots-and-anubhava).